# python multiprocessing after kill process give is_alive() status True

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have gone through the python(3.7) documentation to understand the concept of multiprocessing. For `Process` object there are two methods `terminate()` and `kill`. Terminating a  process is done using the SIGTERM, and killing the process uses the SIGKILL signal on Unix.

When we terminate the process and check `is_alive()` status of the process it gives `False`. but, when I use kill and check the status for the process it gives `is_alive()` status True. I don't know why it's giving True after killing the process if it is the same as the terminate process.

```
def test():
    print("in test method")
    time.sleep(3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=test)
    p1.start()  # start process

    # kill process after 1 sec
    time.sleep(1)
    p1.kill()
    print(p1.is_alive())  # why process alive status true when kill process
    time.sleep(3)
    print(p1.is_alive())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether you use `kill` or `terminate`, these methods only start the termination of the process. You must then wait for the process to *fully* terminate by using `join` (if you try to use `sleep`, you are only guessing as to how long to sleep for the process to be fully terminated):

```
p1.kill()
p1.join() # wait for p1 to fully complete
print(p1.is_alive()) # prints False
```

Comment: `kill()` method is new in python version 3.7. and I'm asking for 3.7, not 3.6

Comment: I have now tested this on 3.8 with both kill and terminate. It doesn't matter: Either one does not immediately cause the process to terminate but just starts the termination. `join` will wait for the actual end of the process. Using `sleep` is not the way to do it.

Comment: Did you *carefully* read my comment? Whether you use `kill` (in 3.7) or `terminate` it doesn't matter. **Neither one instantly terminates the process, it just starts the termination**.

Comment: I've updated the answer to remove the 3.6 confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason of this is that the time between `p1.kill()` and `print(p1.is_alive())` functions is so short. So I think that, the interpreter is trying to print on the screen whether or not the process is still active before this kill command is finished.

For example if you put `time.sleep(0.001)` between `p1.kill()` and `print(p1.is_alive())` functions,  `False` value will be printed rather than `True` value.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process


def test():
    print("in test method")
    time.sleep(3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=test)
    p1.start()  # start process

    # kill process after 1 sec
    time.sleep(1)
    p1.kill()
    time.sleep(0.001)  # Wait for p1.kill() function is finished.
    print(p1.is_alive())  # why process alive status true when kill process
    time.sleep(3)
    print(p1.is_alive())
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, it works but why it takes time any idea?

Comment: When the `p1.kill()` function is called, it takes time to be finished. This time can be so short, let's say this code is getting finished less than `0.001` seconds. When you call the `p1.is_alive()` function, the program runs this line before the finished time of the previous line. The `kill` command has been sent, however short after, the program is passing to the next line, so the time difference between the previous line and the current line is shorther than the finished time of the `kill` command. Such a reason came to my mind.